# How to insulate class?

Tags: c++, class, encapsulation

**foo.h**

```
class Foo {};

namespace {
    class Bar {};
   //...
}
```

**foo.cpp**

```
Foo foo; // Ok

Bar bar; // Ok, but I want Error!
```

How to hide (insulate) *class Bar* in **.cpp* file?

i.e. I do not want to import the `class Bar {}` from **.h* file into *.*cpp* file

Perhaps there is some kind of encapsulation technology for classes?

Comment: `Bar bar;` can not possibly be OK. It is a class template so it needs a template argument.

Comment: Do not use unnamed namespaces in headers, to start with, and do not add anything that you want to be only accessible in the .cpp in the header in general. If it should not be accessible from outside, why is it in the header in the first place?

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas, I'm just curious how it can be done

Comment: @Algorithm: You are curious as of how to provide in a header something that you don't want users of your header to use? Simple, not doing it. *Doctor, it hurts when I do this. Don't do it*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking for. If you only want `Bar` to be visible inside a particular `.cpp` file, that's pretty easy:

foo.h:

```
// add include guard here.
class Foo {};
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

namespace {
    class Bar {};
}

Foo foo;

Bar bar;
```

Note that this restricts *all* visibility of `Bar` to `foo.cpp` though. Nothing outside `foo.cpp` will realize that it even exists.

There's not really a way to make a class only visible inside a header though -- the whole point of a header is that you include it in one or more `.cpp` files, and when you do that, whatever it contains becomes visible inside that `.cpp` file.

If that's what you think you want, chances are pretty good that you need to take a step back and tell us what you're really trying to accomplish. There's probably a way, but the way you're trying to go is almost certainly wrong. The basic division is that headers are for things that will be visible in general; anything that's private gets restricted to implementation (`.cpp`) files.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
class Foo
{
private:
     struct Bar
     {

     };

     void func()
     {
         Bar b; //ok
     }
};


int main()
{

    Foo f; //ok
    Foo::Bar b; //error


    return 0;
}
```